# combining ifelse statement mutate and sequence in dplyr pipe

Tags: r, if-statement, dplyr

I want to replace cities names in a D3.js bubble chart like this one
[How to display d3 bubbles in different colors for a dataset with one branch and many children?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20004063/how-to-display-d3-bubbles-in-different-colors-for-a-dataset-with-one-branch-and)

I have a lot of "small cities" to visualise and I want to replace their labels by an id. for better display (and create a legend).

Here's a small exemple

```
cities <- c("Brest", "Rennes", "Rennes", "Rennes", "Nantes", "Lorient") 
dataset <- data.frame(cities)  
dataset

dataset <- dataset %>%
count(cities)
```

Here's my result: n = 1 (1 = "small cities")

```
cities     1
Brest      1
Lorient    1
Nantes     1
Rennes     3
```

small cities =

What I expect:

A sequence of id's for cities with n = 1 (1 = "small cities")

```
cities     n     id_sequence
Brest      1     1
Lorient    1     2
Nantes     1     3
Rennes     3     NA
```

I am trying to complete my pipe without success with :

```
dataset <- dataset %>%
   count(cities) %>% 
   mutate (id_sequence = ifelse (n = 1:length(cities))
```

Thank you for helping!

Comment: You set the condition as the sequence.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

We can try

```
dataset %>% 
    count(cities) %>% 
    group_by(grp = n==1) %>%
    mutate(id_sequence = row_number()*NA^!grp) %>%
    ungroup() %>% 
    select(-grp)
#    cities     n id_sequence
#    <fctr> <int>       <dbl>
#1   Brest     1           1
#2 Lorient     1           2
#3  Nantes     1           3
#4  Rennes     3          NA
```

Comment: That's great @akrun!

Comment: can I make a variation of my question replacing NA with cities names @akrun ?

Comment: @Wilcar You can use `dataset %>%  count(cities) %>% group_by(grp = n==1) %>%mutate(id_sequence = if_else(grp, as.character(row_number()), as.character(cities))) %>% ungroup() %>% select(-grp)`

Answer (score 3):

You can do this as follows:

```
dataset %>%
   count(cities) %>%
   group_by(n) %>%
   mutate(id_sequence = ifelse(n == 1, 1:n(), NA))
## Source: local data frame [4 x 3]
## Groups: n [2]
## 
##    cities     n id_sequence
##    <fctr> <int>       <int>
## 1   Brest     1           1
## 2 Lorient     1           2
## 3  Nantes     1           3
## 4  Rennes     3          NA
```

The idea here is to group by the column that contains the counts. Inside `mutate()`, `n()` will give the number of rows in each group. For the group where `n == 1`, `n()` will return 3.

Comment: The sequence must begin by 1 without gaps for my legend.

Comment: That's what this solution does.

Comment: thank you for helping . sorry but not in my larger "real" dataset.

Comment: But in that case, your real data is very different from the one you should. The code I used will always label the cities with a count of 1 with a consecutive series starting at 1 and with no gaps.

Comment: You are right about that. I'm just struggling to see how it is possible that akrun's solution works while this one does not. They are basically doing the same since `row_numbers()` is equivalent to `1:n()`.

Comment: my data are on https://github.com/wcariou/The-Trans-Atlantic-Slave-Trade-Db

Answer (score 1):

When `dplyr`is not a requirement:

```
cities <- c("Brest", "Rennes", "Rennes", "Rennes", "Nantes", "Lorient") 
dataset <- data.frame(cities)  
dataset

dataset <- dataset %>%
  count(cities)

dataset$id_sequence <- NA

sequence <- seq(dim(dataset[dataset$n == 1,])[1])

dataset[dataset$n == 1,]$id_sequence <- sequence
```